# What is the preposition associated with "admiration"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Is it "admiration for" or "admiration of"?

For instance, does the sentence "He had a great admiration of Washington Irving." make sense?

Comment: @Carlo_R.: Posted it as an answer

Comment: *Have admiration **for***; *Do sth./ Be in admiration **of**'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly there's a US/UK divide here. I don't much like OP's example usage.

It's not obvious why the adjective *"great"* should affect the acceptable preposition either, but I must say *"He had an admiration of Washington Irving"* sounds awful to me. I'd always use *for*, and drop the article...

> He had great admiration **for** Washington Irving.

EDIT: As @Armen Ծիրունյան's answer points out, *admiration **of*** still occurs fairly often, but it usually occurs in "adjectival" constructions involving *[to be] in admiration **of***. Where *admiration* has a more overt "noun" sense, we use *[to have] [an] admiration **for***...

[[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMKh8.png)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was%20in%20admiration%20of%2Cwas%20in%20admiration%20for%2Chad%20admiration%20of%2Chad%20admiration%20for&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20in%20admiration%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20admiration%20for%3B%2Cc0)

Note that the "alternative" versions *(was in admiration for, had admiration of)* don't occur often enough to show on the chart. Clearly the vast majority of writers use **for** in OP's context.

Answer (score 2):

Both *admiration of* and *admiration for* are correct, and have the same meaning. [Google NGrams Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=admiration%20of,%20admiration%20for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows that although *admiration of* used to be prevalent before 1920, neither has a decisive upper hand now.